# Make tau larger throughout the article

Tags: macros

I want to make the tau large size in the whole article. Hence I try with the `\newcommand` but it fails. here is my command

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\ta}{\Large \tau}
\begin{document}
$\ta$
\end{document}
```

It does not give the large size tau. Please help me.

Comment: `$\ta$` since that is the name of your newcommand

Comment: `\Large` is a text-mode command. Don't use it for math material.

Comment: Please advise whether the (resized) tau symbol may occur in subscript and superscript positions in your document.

Comment: Just for curiosity: You are sure that you want a large `\tau`, not a `\mathcal{T}`.

Comment: Yea want the large \tau not the second one

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I want to make `\tau` large[r] in the whole article.

I suggest you load the `graphicx` package and use its `\scalebox` directive to resize the `\tau` symbol.

[image]

Why the factor `1.44`?, you may ask. It's because `\Large`, which you used in your sample code, increases the font size by the factor 1.44. Obviously, you're free to choose a different scaling factor.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\let\origtau\tau % save the original form of '\tau'
\renewcommand{\tau}{\scalebox{1.44}{$\origtau$}}
\begin{document}
$\tau$ vs.\ $\origtau$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Does it behave properly in sub- and superscript, though, since you ask about it in the question comments? ;)

Comment: @thymaro - That's exactly why I asked the question. As the OP didn't provide a reason (or reasons) for wishing to make the symbol larger, it's hazardous to guess what might be appropriate for superscript and subscript situations. My hunch is that should the symbol occur in first- and/or second-level superscripts and subscripts, one ought to use `\origtau`, not the redefined `\tau`.

Comment: I think this deserves to be mentioned (and illustrated) in your answer

Comment: @thymaro - Good idea. I'll hold off, though, for the time being, in the hope that the OP will weigh in with further information.

Comment: if you want to keep the original tau as `tau`, you can just define the enlarged tau by replacing `renewcommand` simply by `newcommand`

Answer (score 7):

Like egreg, I make it as big as a capital letter.  In this MWE, the `scalerel` package automatically accounts for the current math style.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\let\lctau\tau % save the lowercase of '\tau'
\renewcommand{\tau}{\scalerel*{\lctau}{X}}
\begin{document}
Normal $A+\tau\ne a+\lctau$ and subscript $A_{\tau}\ne A_\lctau$.

Also $\tau+X$ to show it is as big as a capital letter.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

I guess you want the letter to be as high as capital letters:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,graphicx}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\ctau}{{% capital tau
  \mathpalette\cap@greek\tau
}}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\csigma}{{% capital sigma
  \mathpalette\cap@greek\sigma
}}
\newcommand{\cap@greek}[2]{%
  \begingroup
  \sbox\z@{$#1T$}% measure a capital letter in the current style
  \resizebox{!}{\ht\z@}{$\m@th#1#2$}% resize tau to match
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Normal $A+\ctau\ne a+\tau$ and subscript $A_{\ctau}\ne A_\tau$.

Also $\ctau+\csigma$ to show you can define similar commands.

\end{document}
```

[image]