# Setting the tau letter size larger in a document

Tags: macros

There is an idea on this page [Make tau larger throughout the article](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/413880/make-tau-larger-throughout-the-article) to make the letter tau larger, but how can I change the size of some greek letters without renewcommand.

I want to do it like this

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}


\begin{document}
$ \left( X,\tau\right)  $   
\end{document}
```

it produces smaller tau

[image]

Comment: The question is quite unclear. Why do you want the tau larger without using `\renewcommand`? Note, that there are also answers using `\newcommand` instead of `\renewcommand`. So there are also answers to scale the tau only once, if this would be the reason for not using `\renewcommand`.

Comment: @cabohah Because I write documents on Scientific Workplace 5.5, so I dont want to change command. I want to set the size of tau in preamble.

Comment: Redefining a command in the document preamble would change the size in the preamble. Thus, this is exactly what you are looking for according to your explanation, but unfortunately reject.

Comment: @cabohah https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/413887/203843. It is changed as \origtau. But when I reopened document on Scientific Workplace 5.5, Scientific workplace does not recognize renewcommand.

Comment: Have you tested it? Because the small tau is `\origtau`. The large one is `\tau`, after the `\renewcommand`. And you want to have the large one. And there are more answers, which also have the large one as `\tau`. And there are also answers with the large one with a new name. So there are all variation you could expect. So what's the problem? Saving a SWP document inclusive all preamble code?

Comment: @cabohah Yes, it works \usepackage{scalerel} https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/413905/203843. I was not aware of this. Actually, I wanted to set the size manually. This is a more useful solution.

Comment: why do you want a lower case tau to be the size of an uppercase X, isn't that going to be confusing to read?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Actually, I think it's better to read, it looks more elegant especially when capitalized subscript is used

Comment: but you know in advance what you intend, a reader is not going to expect an over-sized lowercase so will wonder if it's a styled latin T or capital tau Τ, such as 

Comment: @DavidCarlisle That's how Sidney Morris uses it in his book Topology without Tears, and it's more readable to me than little tau.